# Finite subgroup of $Gl(n,\mathbb Z)$ and congruences

Tags: gr.group-theory, congruences, linear-algebra

Suppose we have an invertible matrix q in a finite subgroup $Q$ of
$Gl(n,\mathbb Z)$, the group of all invertible integer matrices. Now I want to
find all $x\; mod\; \mathbb Z^n$ for which

$(q+q^2+q^3+...+q^m).x = 0\quad    mod\;  \mathbb Z^n$

where $m$ is the order of $q$ in the finite subgroup $Q$ of $Gl(n,\mathbb Z)$ so that
$q^m=1$. I tried using the Smith normal form so that

$(q+q^2+q^3+...+q^m) = U.D.V$

where $U,V$ in $Gl(n,\mathbb Z)$ and $D$ the Smith normal form, so we have to solve

$D.V.x=0\quad    mod\;  \mathbb Z^n$

Since $D.V$ is diagonal, $x$ must have rational components unless the diagonal element is zero. Now my question is, what is the maximal denominator of the components in $x$ ? So what is the maximal absolute value in $D.V$ ?I think this must be $m$, but I can't figure out why.

**Edit:**
Let me clarify why I expect x to be rational with an upper bound on the denominator. Suppose G is a subgroup of the Euclidean Group with isometries (t,q) as elements (t: translational part, q: linear part). The subgroup T which contains all isometries in G with trivial linear part is a normal subgroup of G. Suppose now that T can be identified with a $\mathbb Z$-lattice in $\mathbb R^n$, then G/T is isomorph with a finite subgroup Q of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$. Crystallographers call G a space group and Q a point group.

There are only finite many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$, so there are only finite many point groups up to conjugacy in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$. Now I want to understand why from this finite number of point groups, a finite number of (non-equivalent) space groups can be deduced. If we write G as the union of cosets of T

$G=\bigcup_{i=1}^{|Q|}(t_{qi},q_{i})T$

we see that (composition of two isometries and q belongs to exactly one coset)

$t_{q_1.q_2}=t_{q_1}+q_1.t_{q_2}  \quad mod\ \mathbb Z^n$

So we know that $t_{q}$ is a real vector $0\leq t_{q}<1$. Using the previous property we also find that (m order of q)

$(t_{q},q)^{m}=(q^{1}\cdot t_{q}+\cdots+q^{m}\cdot t_{q},q^m)\in (0,id)T$

$\Leftrightarrow (q^{1}+\cdots+q^{m})\cdot t_{q}=0\quad mod\ \mathbb{Z}^{n}$

If an appropriate origin is chosen in Euclidean space, $t_{q}$ should be rational with maximal denominator $m$. Maybe investigating $(t_{q},q)^{m}$ is not the best way to find bounds on $t_{q}$?

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't $q+q^2+q^3+...+q^m=1+q+q^2+...+q^{m-1}$ the inverse of $1-q$ (where $1$ means the identity matrix), and thus invertible over $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ as well?

Comment: No, it isn't the inverse, since $(1+ q + \dots + q^{m-1})(1-q)=0$. But this shows that the columns of $1-q$ are in the "kernel" of $1+q+\dots +q^{m-1}$. 

Comment: Isn't the point that your matrix has the form $mE$ for some idempotent matrix $E$, and is also integral?

Comment: Ah, right. Another of my $0$-$1$ mixups.

Comment: @Ralph: you're right, fixed it.

Comment: Can you give some motivation, why the existence of a $t_q$ with rational componets of max. denominator $m$ shows that there are, up to isomorphism, only finitely many groups $G$ ? 

Comment: $G/T$ with elements $(t_q,q)T$ is isomorph with a finite subgroup $Q$ of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ because $q$ must be an element of the automorphism group of the $\mathbb Z$-lattice in Euclidean vector space which is isomorphic to $T$. We know that there are only finite many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$. If the possible translations for each Q are rational between 0 and 1 with maximal denominator $|Q|$ for a specific origin, then we find finite many space groups up to origin shift and conjugacy of their quotient group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I couldn't resist my predilection for generalizations: Using  darij grinberg's simplification, the proof below shows:

Let $k$ be a field, $q \in GL_n(k)$ a matrix of finite exponent $m$ with char$(k) \nmid m$ and $M \subseteq k^n$. Futhermore, let $E$ be the eigenspace of $q$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$  and let $U \le k^n$ be the space spanned by the columns of $1-q$. Then the following is true for $A := 1+q+\dots + q^{m-1}$:

> - $\lbrace x \in k^n \mid Ax \in M \rbrace = U + \frac{1}{m}(E \cap M)$
> - $U$ and $(1/m)(E \cap M)$ intersect in $0$ iff $0 \in M$, otherwise the intersection is empty
> - $A$ is diagonizable with diagonal $(m,...,m,0,...,0)$ where the number of m's equals $\dim E$

---

*(Older formulation)*

Let $E \le \mathbb{C}^n$ be the eigenspace of $1$ of the matrix $q$ and let $U \le \mathbb{C}^n$ be the space spanned by the columns of $1-q$.

Set $A := 1+q+\dots + q^{m-1}$ and $X:= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid A\cdot x \in \mathbb{Z}^n \rbrace$ and $L := E \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Then the following holds:

> $X = U \oplus \frac{1}{m}L$.

*Proof*: Assume $\dim E = d$. Then $\dim U = \text{rank}(1-q) = n-d$.

Since each $x \in E$ satisfies $Ax = mx$, $E$ contains eigenvectors from $A$ of the eigenvalue $m$. From $A \cdot (1-q) = 0$ it follows that $U$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$ of the eigenvalue $0$. Hence $E \cap U = 0$ and for dimensional reasons 
$$\mathbb{C}^n = U \oplus E.$$
Since $q$ has integral entries, it's possible to chosse a basis of $E$ in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and by multiplying with a suitable integer it's also possible to choose a basis in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Therefore $L = E \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a lattice of rank $d$. Let $\lbrace e_1, \dots, e_d \rbrace$ be a basis of $L$. Let $x \in X$ and write 
$$x = u + \sum_i \alpha_i e_i \text{ with } \alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}.$$
Then $Ax = \sum_i m\alpha_i e_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $q(Ax) = Ax$. It follows $Ax \in E \cap \mathbb{Z}^n = L = \oplus_i \mathbb{Z}e_i$ and therefore $m\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. This shows $X \subseteq U \oplus (1/m)L$. The converse inclusion is obvious.  *qed*.

**Edit:** Also note that the image of $A$ is given by 
$$ Y := \lbrace Ax \mid x \in X \rbrace = L.$$

Comment: Am I off track here or is it possible that your proof can be simplified as follows: Instead of writing $x = u+\sum\limits_i \alpha_i e_i$ with $\alpha_i\in \mathbb C$, let me write $x=u+e$ for some $u\in U$ and $e\in E$. Then, $Ax=me\in\mathbb Z^n$ and $q\left(Ax\right)=Ax$. This yields $Ax\in E\cap \mathbb Z^n = L$, so that $me=Ax\in L$ and thus $e\in\frac{1}{m}L$, so that $x = u + e \in U \oplus \frac{1}{m}L$. Nowhere we are using a basis of $E$ or any other property of lattices. Too simple to be true?

Comment: Looks good. So the problem can be solved completely by means of linear algebra. In fact, it would be a nice exercise in a LA course. 

Comment: In your generalization, you should require $M$ to have some structure.

Comment: Well, you are right, the direct sum isn't appropriate. But the result holds for every subset $M$, if one defines (see the change in the last edit) $A+B := \lbrace a+b \mid a \in A, b \in B \rbrace$ for subsets $A, B \subseteq k^n$ (of course, $A+B = \emptyset$, if $A$ or $B$ empty). 

Comment: I forgot to mention that $x\in \mathbb R^n$

Comment: No problem, just replace $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}$. 

Comment: Thanks Ralph and Darij, you solved my original question. However the result is not what I expected from its context (see the edited question). This is because there is another variable involved: the origin shift in Euclidean space. I suspect that your solution $U+\frac{1}{m}(E\cap M)$ might be simplified by choosing an appropriate origin. I'm struggling however to find this origin. I added the secondary question as an answer or do you think I should post a new question?

Comment: I think you will receive more feedback/answers when it's posted as a new question. It will also be helpful for the reader to know a little about your motivation: I understand that you are looking for a proof why there are only finitely many space groups (up to ismomorphism). Are  you looking for a particular proof (e.g. along the lines 
you sketched) or will alternative proofs also do ? Have you looked at proofs in the literature ? 

Comment: I think it boils down to proving that $Col(q-1)\cap Col(p-1)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ when q and p are generators of a finite subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

That's an answer/comment to the secondary question.

I don't know, if the result can be derived from the finiteness of the matrix $q$ alone (it seems to me that you don't explore the fact that a space group consists of isometries). There is another point that makes me wonder: At the begining you are considering an isometry $(x,q)$ with $q \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. But then $q \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z}) \cap O_n =P$, the group of permutation matrices with signed entries. Aren't there space groups, those rotational parts form larger groups than $P$ ?

That said, I was looking in the internet and found a paper ([link](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/bucher/Affine/pdfAffine/BuserBieberbach.pdf)), having a proof (section 5) that is somewhat related to your approach in the Edit-part of the original question.

The idea is roughly: Let $G$ be a space group with translation subgroup $T$  and let $L$ be the lattice correspnding to $T$. Choose a system of representatives $\lbrace q_1, ...,q_m \rbrace$ for $G/T$ and a basis $\lbrace b_1, ..., b_n \rbrace$ of $L$. Let $a_i$ be the translational part of $q_i$. By writing $a_i$ as linear combination of the $b_j$ it follows that $q_i$ can be choosen such that $|a_i| \le |b_1| + ... + |b_n| =: \alpha$ (Euklid-Norm). If $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let $[x_0]$ denote translation by $x_0$. Then  the following product can be expressed as

$$q_i \circ q_j = [\sum_k l_{ijk}b_k] \circ q_{\eta(i,j)},\hspace{10pt} l_{ijk} \in \mathbb{Z},\quad \eta(i,j) \in \lbrace 1,...,m \rbrace \hspace{50pt} (\ast)$$

It's easy to see, that the group law of $G$ is uniquely determined by $(\ast)$.

If $G'$ is another space group with $(G':T') = (G:T)$, repeat the same procedure and define a mapping $G \to G'$ by $q_i \to q'_i$, $b_j \to b_j'$. If $l_{ijk}' = l_{ijk}$ and $\eta(i,j)' = \eta(i,j)$ for all $i,j,k$, this is an isomorphism. Therefore there are only finitely many space groups $G$ for  fixed $(G:T)$ (up to isomorphism), if it can be shown that there are only finitely many possible values for the $l_{ijk}$.

If the rotational part of $q_i$ is the matrix $A_i \in O_n$, $(\ast)$ shows 
$$ | \sum_k l_{ijk}b_k | = |a_i + A_ia_j-A_iA_j(A_{\eta(i,j)})^{-1} a_{\eta(i,j)}| \le |a_i| + |a_j| + |a_{\eta(i,j)}| \le 3\alpha$$

Suppose $\lbrace b_1, ..., b_n\rbrace$ is an orthonormal base of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\alpha = n$ and each $|l_{ijk}| \le 3n$ is bounded. Thus the result is shown in this case. In general, a similar estimate holds, but it's harder to establish (that's step 2 on page 144 that relies on lemmas 4.1, 4.2).

**Remark:** Using the theory of group extensions, the result follows easily from the  finiteness of $H^2(Q; \mathbb{Z}^n)$ for finite groups $Q$.

Comment: Why is $q \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z}) \cap O_n$? The linear parts of isometries are orthogonal transformations, but don't necessarily correspond to orthogonal matrices (only for an orthonormal basis). So either $q\in O(n,\mathbb{R})$ or $q \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. So loosing orthogonality is the price we pay for wanting integer matrices. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The fact that $(q+q^2+q^3+...+q^m).x = 0\quad    mod\;  \mathbb Z^n$ results from considering isometries and the properties of space groups, so I do explore the fact that a space group consists of isometries.

Comment: Anyway, you answered my original question and got me on the right track for the secondary problem. Thanks Ralph!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This is a secondary question on how Ralph's solution can be simplified by choosing an appropriate origin in Euclidean space.**

Ralph's solution to my original question, in the context of space groups, states that an isometry $(x,q)$ in a space group $G$ with linear part $q\in Q< GL(Z^n)$, must have a translational part x for which

$X_q=\lbrace x\in\mathbb R^n: (q^{1}+\cdots+q^{m})\cdot x\in \mathbb Z^n\rbrace =Col(q-1)+\frac{1}{m}(Null(q-1)\cap \mathbb Z^n)$

Note first that from the composition of isometries we find that

$(t_1,q_1)(t_2,q_2)=(t_1+q_1\cdot t_2,q_1\cdot q_2)$

$\Leftrightarrow X_{q_{1}\cdot q_{2}}=X_{q_{1}}+(q_{1}-1)\cdot X_{q_{2}}$

This means that we must only consider the $X_q$ for the generators of the finite group $Q< GL(Z^n)$ (i.e. the point group).

After a shift of origin in Euclidean space, i.e. an affine transformation $(v,1)$ with $v\in \mathbb R^n$, we can write that

$X_q'=Col(q-1)+\frac{1}{m}(Null(q-1)\cap \mathbb Z^n)+(q-1)\cdot v$

Since $(q-1)\cdot v\in Col(q-1)$, we can find for every $u\in Col(q-1)$ a vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$ for which $(q-1)\cdot v=-u$. Thus for a proper choice of origin we can write for a generator q

$X_q=\frac{1}{m}(Null(q-1)\cap \mathbb Z^n)$

so that $t_q = X_q\ mod\ \mathbb Z^n$ is a rational number with maximal denominator $|Q|$ (which is the maximal possible m). The question is now, can we find one $v\in \mathbb R^n$ so that this simplification can be done for all $X_q$? For this, the column spaces $Col(q-1)$ for generators q of Q should be linear independent. If we call $S$ the generating set of Q, then this can be expressed as

$\forall q,p\in S: Col(q-1)\cap Col(p-1)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$

Is this true?

Comment: One can't always find generators q with $Col(q-1)$ intersection $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ for a point group, so this is not the way to go.